# How to sort array of times with AM and PM at the end in descending order in Java

Tags: java

I Have an array list as below

```
 {"8:00 am", "8:32 am", "8:10 am", "1:00 pm", "3:00 pm", "2:00 pm"}
```

I  tried using Collections sort but I couldn't get the desired output
I need to get the output sorted as below

```
{3:00 pm, 2:00 pm, 1:00 pm, 8:32 am, 8:10 am, 8:00 am}
```

Comment: Your best approach is to convert the Strings to LocalTime Objects and work with those.

Comment: Please post your codes here. It will help others to easily solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string into [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) by using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so that it sorts the array based on time

```
Arrays.sort(time, Comparator.comparing(str->LocalTime.parse(str.toUpperCase(),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a"))));
```

If you want descending order you can simply use reverse `Comparator`

```
Comparator.comparing((String str)->LocalTime.parse(str.toUpperCase(),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a"))).reversed()
```